fetch user from supabase in the server in the hole app with next js pages router
I'm trying to migrate my nextjs app from client side to server side. I'm using supabase for database and authentication.
I want to fetch the user auth in the server, to make it smooth and redirect or show the user different components depending on it's auth status.
Currently I fetch the session in the _app.tsx file and set the useUser context there. Is there a way to doy it server side? I have follow the supabase docs and I already use getServerSideProps in the /login page, and works fine.
How I use getServerSideProps:
export async function getServerSideProps(context: GetServerSidePropsContext) {
  const supabase = createClient(context);

  const { data } = await supabase.auth.getUser();

  if (data) {
    return {
      redirect: {
        destination: "/",
        permanent: false,
      },
    };
  }

  return {
    props: {
      user: data || null,
    },
  };
}

My current _app.tsx file:
import * as React from "react";
import "../styles/globals.css";
import { createClientComponentClient } from "@supabase/auth-helpers-nextjs";
import { SessionContextProvider, Session } from "@supabase/auth-helpers-react";
import { AppProps } from "next/app";
import UserProvider from "../contexts/user-data";
import { Toaster } from "sonner";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import { createClient } from "@/lib/supabase-helpers/component";

const supabaseUrl = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_PROJECT_URL;
const supabaseAnonKey = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_ANON_PUBLIC;

function MyApp({
  Component,
  pageProps,
}: AppProps<{
  initialSession: Session;
}>) {
  // Create a new supabase browser client on every first render.
  const [supabaseClient] = React.useState(() =>
    createClientComponentClient({
      supabaseUrl: supabaseUrl,
      supabaseKey: supabaseAnonKey,
    })
  );

  const [session, setSession] = React.useState<Session | null>(null);

  const router = useRouter();
  const supabase = createClient();

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const locale = localStorage.getItem("locale");

    const currentPath = router.asPath;
    if (locale && currentPath) {
      router.push(currentPath, currentPath, { locale });
    }
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [router.asPath]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (session?.user.id) return;

    const getSession = async () => {
      const { data, error } = await supabase.auth.getSession();

      if (error) {
        return;
      }

      if (data && data.session) {
        setSession(data.session);
      } else {
        setSession(null);
      }
    };

    getSession();
  }, [session?.user.id, router.asPath]); // Call getSession only once on first render

  return (
    <SessionContextProvider
      supabaseClient={supabaseClient}
      initialSession={pageProps.initialSession}
    >
      <UserProvider session={session}>
        <Toaster />
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </UserProvider>
    </SessionContextProvider>
  );
}

export default MyApp;

